# Send input text to controller's scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html page:

```
<div class="rtm-nav">
    <div ng-app>
    <body ng-controller="DemandCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
        <label>From:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ctrl.dataa.from">
        </label>
        <label>To:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ctrl.dataa.to">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />

        <script src="demand/demand.js"></script>
    </body> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to save the input text from the 2 text boxes in the controller's scope. This is how I tried to do it:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        debugger;
        this.dataa = {
            from: ctrl.dataa.from,
            to: ctrl.dataa.to
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

}
```

I get the error saying:

> ReferenceError: ctrl.dataa is not defined

Is any better method to send the data from input text to the controller?

Comment: Variable ctrl is undefined. This is the reason why you have this error.

Comment: See your constructor (dataa object initialisation), it's either `ng-model="dataa.to"` or `ng-controller="DemandCtrl as ctrl"`

Comment: I think when controller as syntax use then should use ctrl.dataa = {}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined scope which is accepted by your controller. That's why you can't read data from the form. I would also suggest to use `<form>` to deal with any kind of data submission. So take a look at the refactored example of yours:

==== HTML ======

```
    <div class="rtm-nav">
        <div ng-app="my-app">
          <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="DemandCtrl">
            <label>From:
                <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ctrl.data.from">
            </label>
            <label>To:
                <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ctrl.data.to">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
          </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

===== Controller

```
    angular.module('my-app', [])
       .controller('DemandCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.submit = function() {
                let data = {
                    from: $scope.ctrl.data.from,
                    to: $scope.ctrl.data.to,
                }
               console.log(data);
            };
    });
```